# Wavefunction's inner product

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space

When two wavefunctions are orthogonal we can write that

$$\langle\Psi_n|\Psi_m\rangle=\delta_{mn}$$

This means that

$$\langle\Psi_1|\Psi_2\rangle=\langle\Psi_2|\Psi_1\rangle=0$$

But if the two wavefunctions aren't orthogonal but $\langle\Psi_1|\Psi_2\rangle=d \in\mathbb{R}$ is real, can we then conclude that $\langle\Psi_2|\Psi_1\rangle=\langle\Psi_1|\Psi_2\rangle$?

Comment: Yes, the inner product is conjugate symmetric.

Comment: In fact, isn't that one of its defining properties?

Comment: @ShuchangZhang: Thank you very much for your comment. I cannot understand, however why is that so. $\Psi_1^*$ is a row vector with complex coordinates while $\Psi_2$ is a similar column vector.

Comment: @Thanos It has nothing to do with whether a vector is row or column. The definition of inner product requires two vectors to obtain a scalar with three properties (bilinear, conjugate symmetry and positive definite).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, indeed, $\langle\Psi_1|\Psi_2\rangle=d\in\mathbb R$, you are right. In general, however, $\langle\Psi_1|\Psi_2\rangle=d\in\mathbb C$ and then we have

$\langle\Psi_2|\Psi_1\rangle = \langle\Psi_1|\Psi_2\rangle^*=d^*$

where the asterisks denotes complex conjugation. This can be seen from the definition of the inner product in terms of wavefunctions:

$\langle\Psi_2|\Psi_1\rangle = \int dx\langle\Psi_2|x\rangle\langle x|\Psi_1\rangle = \int dx \Psi_2^*(x)\Psi_1(x) = \left(\int dx \Psi_1^*(x)\Psi_2(x)\right)^* = \left(\int dx \langle\Psi_1|x\rangle\langle x|\Psi_2\rangle\right)^* = \langle\Psi_1|\Psi_2\rangle^*$

One more comment on the distinction of states and wavefunctions. $\langle\Psi_1|\Psi_2\rangle$ is the inner product of two states, $|\Psi_1\rangle$ and $|\Psi_2\rangle$. Those states can equivalently be represented by wavefunctions, $\Psi_1(x)=\langle x|\Psi_1\rangle$ which are essentially nothing but the inner product with the eigenstates of the position basis.

Comment: @dj_mummy: I fully understand the notation! Thank you!!!